# Chrome extension to show page size in the title bar

Tags: chrome

I'd like to get familiar with how large 'average' webpages are, but I don't want to dig for the information.

Must:

- Run on Chrome latest (64-bit) on OS X 10.10
- Tell me, at page load, how much data was downloaded to render the page
- Be easily accessible, I.e. not have to open the dev tools to get to it.
- Display sizes in human-friendly format - `980 kB`, not `980709 bytes`

Should:

- Include data downloaded after page load, but I'm not as concerned about that.
- Ideally live in the title bar, to the right of the url bar.

Answer (score 0):

Close matches (found by searching Chrome Web Store):

- [Page Size](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-size/nkciggjljncfhmafbkfcmffnbfedeiii):

  > This is a quick and easy extension that will just let you know the page size and view state. The view state is really only for aspx pages but the page size works anywhere.
- [Size Grabber](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/size-grabber/jgoenlgmmmgickjnnepbpdhjkpfccino/reviews):

  > Reports (in KB) the size of the html of the page.
  >   Note it does NOT include assets of the page (eg js/css/images)

For unknown reasons, Size Grabber does not work for me.

Page Size displays the size in bytes, but otherwise fulfils all other requirements.